# Поиск по нескольким полям с разными значениями

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Как сделать правильно поиск по нескольким полям, учитывая, что для каждого поля свое значения. Делаю что-то подобное:

```
$where = '';
    $where .= (!empty($s))  ? " WHERE one    ='$s' " : ''; 
    $where .= (!empty($s2)) ? " AND  two     ='$s2' " : '';
    $where .= (!empty($s3)) ? " AND  three  ='$s3' " : '';      
    $where .= (!empty($s4)) ? " AND  four    = '$s4' " : '';        
    $where .= (!empty($s5)) ? " AND  five = '$s5' " : '';       
    $where .= (!empty($s6)) ? " AND  six = '$s6' " : '';        
    $where .= (!empty($s7)) ? " AND  seven = '$s7' " : '';      
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM invoices $where";
```

Но в таком случае поле one всегда должно быть заполнено. А мне нужно делать поиск, если будет заполнено хоть одно значение из 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такие штуки - циклы и массивы.

```
$conditions = array();
$columns = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven');
for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
     if (!empty(${'s' . $i})) {
         $conditions[] = sprintf("%s = '%s'", $columns[$i], ${'s' . $i});
     }
}
$query = 'SELECT * FROM invoices';
if (sizeof($conditions)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}
```

А если не забивать переменные с бессмысленными названиями и сразу подойти с умом (получить данные в формате [имяПоля => значение]), то цикл становится еще проще.

```
foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
    if ($value) {
        $conditions[] = sprintf("%s = '%s'", $field, $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`if ($s || $s2 || $s3 || $s4 || $s5 || $s6 || $s7){
    // ваш код
}`